# Android horizontalscrollview child visible width

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Can we get the visible width of a child inside a `horizontalscrollview` ?

i tried

```
int viewLeft = v.getLeft();
int viewRight = v.getRight();
```

but it's always the same result

I need to know if the visibility is higher than half the width

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you need width, use `getWidth()`, for height use `getHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

"Visible width" sounds like you want a child view's width actually visible to the user (whole width minus the currently invisible part(s)).

In that case it's correct to use getLeft() and getRight(), but like this instead (hsv being your HorizontalScrollView instance):

```
int viewLeft = v.getLeft();
int viewRight = v.getRight();
int scrollX = hsv.getScrollX();
if (scrollX > viewLeft) {
    viewLeft = scrollX;
}
if (scrollX < viewRight) {
    viewRight = scrollX + hsv.getWidth();
}
int visibleWidth = viewRight - viewLeft;
```